# Need OpenGL ES 2.0 Emulator

Tags: opengl-es, emulation

I'm getting into Android development and am looking for a good OpenGL ES emulator other than the AVD (doesn't have full opengl es 2.0 support yet)

Suggestions welcome!

Must be free.

Preferably easy to use

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to convince [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/opengles.html) to act as such.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Leapdroid emulator which fully supports opengl es 2.0. http://www.leapdroid.com

Comment: Leapdroid emulator is the fastest android emulator on the market.